# What does "Paths must precede Expression" mean when using find? I have included the single quotes in the command

Tags: find

The command `find / -printf ‘%s %p\n’| sort -nr | head -10`  comes back with this error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: %pn'
```

The command above can be found at https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-free-disk-space-on-linux-systems/ Step 7

I am on CentOS 7. The command `type find` returns `find is hashed (/usr/bin/find)`.

`find` version is as follows:

```
$ find -version
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you copied from misformatted the command with typographic quotes, `‘` and `’`. You need to use straight quotes, `'`:

```
find / -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -10
```

Without this change, `find` receives separate arguments `‘%s` and `%p\n’`. The first is applied to `-printf`, the second ends up an orphan and is treated like a misplaced path argument, resulting in the error message you’re seeing.

Comment: Note: I think there's a bug in 4.5.11 where `find . -name "*.txt"` will fail with the "paths must..." message, if there is more than one file matching the pattern in the current directory. Seems that `find` itself is expanding the glob in the cur dir, as if you ran `find . -name a.txt b.txt` - happens irrespective of quotes. Doesn't happen in 4.8.0, so assuming it's been fixed. Nasty.